# jQuery dialog UI get closed when click on title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I'm using this below code for one of my website. I know there have lot of ways to create a dialog boxes. But for a some reason, I need to follow these structure.

```
//On click trigger a popup box 
$('#terms').click(function(e){
    popupBox(e);
});
//Create a Popup Box 
function popupBox(e){            
    e.preventDefault();
    $('body').width($('body').width());
    $('body').css('overflow', 'hidden');
    $('<div id="popupbox" title="Terms and Conditions"><!-- popupbox - Edit by Yesh  --></div>').appendTo('body')
    .html('<div><h1>Lorem Ipsum Title</h1></div><div><p>Lorem ipsum dolar sit amet </p></div><div><small>Read it before accept</small></div>')
    .dialog({
        modal: true, title: 'Terms and Conditions', zIndex: 9999, autoOpen: true,
        width: '60%', resizable: false,
        close: function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).remove();
            $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
        },
    });
}
```

Problem is when I click on the Title. It's get hidden (not closed). So, how to fix it?

Here my [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/5L7Yr/) is working fine.

Comment: nice - `$('body').width($('body').width());`

Comment: @NicolaeOlariu Thanks buddy. I missed it. :-D. I vote it. But it is not the issue. My [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yeshansachithak/5L7Yr/) is working fine. I'm confused.

Comment: @Neurofluxation Thanks for the comments. Where is the answer?

Comment: could you be more specific?what gets hidden?

Comment: @phpcoderx When click on the `terms` button. I have pop up one dialog box using above code. It's working fine. but, when we click on the title for drag the dialog box. It's hidden.

Comment: @YeshanSachithaKPerera Your JSfiddle is working fine? What version of JqueryUI are you using?

Comment: @phpcoderx I'm using same version that I used in JSFIDDLE.

Comment: Why this down voted? 
Thanks all. @phpcoderx yes man you are right. I changed the `jquery-ui-version` to `1.10.2`. Now all working fine. I used `jquery-ui-version-1.10.4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is related to vertical scrolling.

You're probably scrolled down on the page when you open the dialog. When you then click the title bar of the dialog to drag it, the dialog jumps further down the page, usually hidden from view. The only way to get it to close is to press Esc. Your JSFiddle doesn't show the problem because it's not vertically tall enough to require scrolling.

[Here's a modified version of your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/russellg99/frxtmuhj/11/) with vertical space added to illustrate the problem.

The solution, as described in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24318789/), is to change the style of the dialog from `position: absolute` to `position: fixed`:

`.ui-dialog { position: fixed; }`

[Here's another JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/russellg99/frxtmuhj/13/) with the problem fixed.

Comment: Thanks, but in your JSFiddle, Popup get hide when I try to drag it.

Comment: Yes, that was the point, to show the original problem, since your JSFiddle didn't show it. I just now added a second JSFiddle to this post with an example using the solution I mentioned.

Comment: Thanks, but I was able to fix it by changing jQuery-UI version.

Comment: Yes but the fix I posted works in both versions. Please consider marking my answer as correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is near impossible to answer when there is no way to reproduce the issue you are facing. Try narrowing your problem down:

- What browser are you using? Is the behaviour consistent on all browsers?
- If the problem doesn't reproduce in jsfiddle, maybe the problem is not the code you put in jsfiddle. Try giving it more code from your page until the problem shows itself - then remove as much as you can to isolate the bug.

So in short, show us more code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I used same code in the jsfiddle. But, I can't understand why is this happen in my browsers. I have latest browsers in my laptop