# jQuery UI Dialog Closes When the Title is Clicked ... Sometimes

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a jQuery UI Dialog with some strange behavior: whenever you click or double-click on the header/title of the dialog, there is a chance that it will close the dialog, without removing the modal overlay (double-clicks seem to trigger it more often than clicks, but both are pretty frequent and neither one triggers a close 100% of the time).

The fact that the modal is left behind makes me think that an error is happening, but there's no errors in the console.  I'd be tempted to blame my code, but this behavior happens even when I initialize the dialog with no options at all (`$el.dialog({})`).  I've also tried setting `{close: $.noop}`, to no avail.  However other dialogs elsewhere in our codebase don't have this behavior (even though I can't find any meaningful differences between them except in the CSS).

Does anyone have any idea what's going on, and how I can correct it?

Comment: Could you share the code like in jsFiddle or something

Comment: The problem is there's no code to show; if I do (literally) `$('<div></div>').dialog({});` clicking on the title still closes the dialog.  As I mentioned, there might be some CSS affecting things, but we have thousands of lines of CSS and I have no idea what bit in particular would cause something like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting 
.ui-dialog {
  position: fixed
}

Comment: Thanks for the answer (that should be part of jQuery UI's code ...)

Comment: This is indeed the fix, and the problem is related to vertical scrolling. It happens when you're scrolled down on the page and then open the dialog. Here's a JSFiddle with vertical space added to illustrate the problem: https://jsfiddle.net/russellg99/frxtmuhj/6/